# Basic on Android Client Server

Tags: android

I am new to Android Client server and have a basic doubt.

Consider an android application is requesting a php page say StudentDetails.php and the input will be a student id from the android application through HTTPPOST request.

Now, StudentDetails.php has received the student id, processed and result is ready ( Name, Class, English Marks, Physics marks etc ).

My question is, how this details will be send back to Android application from PHP ?

Regards
Prasath

Comment: Please change the subject of this post. What you want to know has nothing to do with android but only with elementary php programming. So remove android tag please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (the usual, I guess) is to output JSON from your `StudentDetails.php` which you can then process in your app.

So you'd call the PHP page and as a response you'd get something like

```
{
    "studentname": "John Doe",
    "age": 18,
    ...
}
```

In your app you'd consume this JSON (using any suitable JSON library) and from there use it in any way you need.

Comment: Thank you Germi, for your valuable answer